# "Rate this app" google play store link in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I wanted to add "Rate us" `google play store` link for my `Ionic` app. I tried as follows

```
window.open('market://details?id=com.app.id', '_system');

<a href="market://details?id=com.app.id" target="_system">Rate us</a>
```

Both does not work for me. What is the problem in above code? is there any way to do it?

Comment: have you try `target="_top"`

Comment: sorry. it does not work.

Comment: Please read this page. You need market as a link if you are working in android  . Been stuck for hours to find how to achieve this thing.
https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html#OpeningPublisher

Comment: for loading more apps use this market://search?q=pub:<Developer Name>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use this plugin: https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate

I use it with success like this :

```
        AppRate.preferences.useLanguage = cfg.useLanguage;
        AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.ios = cfg.appStoreAppURL.ios;
        AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.android = cfg.appStoreAppURL.android;
        AppRate.preferences.customLocale = cfg.customLocale;
        AppRate.preferences.displayAppName = cfg.displayAppName;
        AppRate.preferences.usesUntilPrompt = cfg.usesUntilPrompt;
        AppRate.preferences.promptAgainForEachNewVersion = false;
        AppRate.promptForRating();
```

Comment: Thanks. But i also uses `AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.android = 'market://details?id=<package_name>'` why it does not work for me?

Comment: I am using this "market://details?id=com.app.id" and it's working. Is this working in your browser ? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.id By the way to use "_system" I think you need the InAppBrowser plugin.

Comment: Great. Afer adding InAppBrowser plugin, it works. Thanks

Comment: @jpwizer does this plugin knows the user has already rated our app, and will disable the popup in the future ? Just don't want to annoy the users.

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer, we need to install  `InAppBrowser` plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Then use the following code

```
window.open('market://details?id=com.app.id', '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible with custom urls!
See here: http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/

install : cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin.git --variable URL_SCHEME=ionicapp

you can redirect it to the market as above link is showing.